# Download documents referenced by a web page with wget

Tags: wget, json

I want to download all the documents pointed to by a web page with wget.

When I run wget, it only downloads the webpage, not all the contents that the web page links to.

```
wget --content-disposition -v -S -r -nc -np -Kk -px --ignore-length \
     --content-disposition --proxy-user "XYZ" --proxy-passwd "PASS" \
     --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies \
     'https://www.website.com/link/live?func=lab&objId=174914395&objAction=browse&viewType=1'
```

Wget downloads only one page which is `https://www.website.com/link/live?func=lab&objId=174914395&objAction=browse&viewType=1`.
That webpage contains:

```
DataStringToVariables( '( {"currentPageNum":1,"totalPages":1,"totalCount":21,"dbTimeTaken":0,"timeTaken":1,"haveBigImages":"fa lse1","myrows":[{"dataId":"177020845","type2":"184","typeName":"Document","name":"Action_Mar_JKill%2Exls", etc.
```

There are many xls,docs, pdf, etc but wget doesn't download them. How can I download them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm getting your question, but I'm going to try and answer anyway.

What you're getting from the URL is [JSONP](http://json-p.org/), but JSONP isn't handled by wget at all. `wget` is just a downloading program, as noted here in the man page for `wget`:

> GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.

`wget` does not support any parsing of the data it receives. If you wish to parse the data, use another programming language to import and process the data received here.

Assuming that you're writing some sort of shell script, you may also wish to use [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk) to fetch the data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk) for an example.

Once you have parsed the JSON(P), you can go ahead and download the files listed from the JSON(P) data with `wget`.

Comment: When passed the `-r` flag, `wget` can parse HTML data for links.